# How can I install jQuery on WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

Please tell me how can I install jQuery on a WordPress blog? I need jquery 1.8.3 but Google provides all others than that. Will jquery 1.8.4 work instead of 1.8.3?
https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide

Comment: there is nothing to do with jquery but wordpress.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? That you don't know if another version of jQuery than 1.8.3 will work with your scripts? If so, you'll have to post your script. Is your question how you can add your own version of jQuery instead of the default provided by Wordpress, then please say so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following is the best way to go about it. Add the following to the theme's functions.php file:

```
if (!is_admin()) add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts", "my_jquery_enqueue", 11);
function my_jquery_enqueue() {
   wp_deregister_script('jquery');
   wp_register_script('jquery', "http" . ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443 ? "s" : "") . "://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js", false, null);
   wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}
```

Or by installing this plugin : https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-jquery-plus/

Link for jquery 1.8.3 : http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js

Also as Jai mentioned in the comments, version 1.8.4 of jquery doesn't exist

Comment: `Will jquery 1.8.4 work instead of 1.8.3?` i think this is the question?

Comment: @Jai I understand that he is having problems finding version 1.8.3

Comment: yeah seems to be but your answer should help him and suggest him there is no `1.8.4`.

Comment: I wanted to make this code work on my website. This answer helped me achieve it. Thanks.
http://jsfiddle.net/chufol/8TH2X/